# Concatenate a custom field and a text string in a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am attempting to use a trigger for Case to input defined text as well as a custom case field value into an autogenerated Case Comment. The custom field value is `Issue_Number__c`. The code snippet is below:

```
casecomment comment = new casecomment(parentid=record.id,commentbody='Ticket '+ Case.Issue_Number__c+ ' has been created for your issue.' ,ispublished=true);
```

The Case Comment successfully generates, but with the following:

```
"Ticket Issue_Number__c has been created for your issue."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating in the field token (`SObjectField`), rather than the field value (`String`). Here is some code to illustrate:

```
String fieldValue = record.Issue_Number__c; // this value is what you want
String fieldToken = Case.Issue_Number__c; // this value is what you are using
```

So simply change `Case.Issue_Number__c` to `record.Issue_Number__c`.

Comment: d'oh, can't believe that I didn't see this as the issue before you answered. +1